# How can i print function default arguments in decorator function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

This my code :

```
def test_deco(func):
    def innrer_func(*args,**kwargs):
        print('args : ',args)
        print('kwargs : ',kwargs)
        return func(*args , **kwargs)
    return innrer_func

@test_deco
def add (x = 2, y= 3 ) :
    return x + y
print(add())
```

And this is my output :

```
args :  ()
kwargs :  {}
5
```

And my question is why `*args` and `**kwargs` is empty but i have right result and how can i pass `x` and `y` into the `test_deco`?

Comment: "why *args and **kwargs is empty " - because they come from what is passed explicitly in the call, not from default arguments. The same would happen if you didn't use a decorator, although it would be harder to demonstrate.

Comment: The [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/inspect.html) module will let you look at a function object's default arguments. Inside your `test_deco`, you could call use it on `func` to find out what the `func`'s default args are, and then build an inner_func accordingly.

Comment: so how can i access to the x , y? can you show me some example please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must use [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/inspect.html) module to do this.

```
import inspect
def test_deco(func):
    def innrer_func(*args):
        result = func(*args)
        try:
            print(f'{args[0]} + {args[1]} = {result}')
        except IndexError:
            default_args = inspect.getcallargs(func , *args)
            print(f'{default_args["x"]} + {default_args["y"]} = {result} | Default Values')
        finally:
            return result
    return innrer_func

@test_deco
def add (x = 5, y = 8 ) :
    return x + y
```